# Change of address via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create the first .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite for index.php?page=xxxx
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC, L]
```

I am learning PHP and would like to change the website address view from example.com/test/1/index.php?page=mysql to example.com/test/1/index/page/mysql.

When I pasted the above  code to .htaccess file , i get a info that the page cannot be found. When I delete a .htaccess file, the page displays correctly. Is there something wrong with my code in the .htaccess file?

I know index.php?page=abc addresses are dangerous. What is the best way to protect or change the appearance of links in php, is the change in the file sufficient?

Thanks for all the advice

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "blocked"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I get a 404 error on the server. When I delete the .htaccess file, the page is displayed.

Comment: Please share more details about that error by editing your question. Which URL are you using?

Comment: I use two possibilities : first : mydomain.com/index/page/mysql  - this is what i want to look like after using commands in the .htaccess file.
second: mydomain.com/index.php?page=mysql - so it is programmed in php code. 
If there is a .htaccess file on the server, it gets a message that there is no such page. and when I delete the .htaccess file from the server, the page is displayed to me

Comment: Changing anything about the “appearance” of your links is of course not at all sufficient, regarding security. If the value `xyz123` was problematic for your application in any way - then it does not matter one bit, whether that value was “input” using a URL like `index/xyz123`, or `index.php?page=xyz123`. If that value could be problematic in any way, then you need to handle that problem _inside_ your script.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please share more details. Which URL are you calling that provokes the problem? If that is `index/page/mysql`: the given regular expression does not match a forward slash

Comment: I don't have  more data to share. The problem must be in the .htaccess file because when .htaccess file is on the server, I can't open my page and I get information that there is no such page. If I delete the file from the server, the page is displayed without any problems from this address: http://example.com/test/1/index.php?page=mysql .

Comment: "Which URL are you calling that provokes the problem" should be something that is easy to answer. Please edit your question to contain an URL you've tried to call, and the error message you are facing

Comment: Just to check this once more: you try to match a URL with **multiple** slashes? The given `RewriteRule` does not match here, as it does not contain slashes intiehr regular expression

Comment: I edited my post and i hopefully it is more visible now. I want change URL adress from example.com/test/1/index.php?page=mysql to example.com/test/1/index/page/mysql. 
If the .htaccess file is on the server, both addresses do not work.  Then I get a 404 error

Comment: Following your advice, I added one more section with slashes (you can see it in the question above), but unfortunately I still have the same problem, "there is no such page"

Comment: Then please share more details about your application. `example.com/test/1/index/page/mysql` would mean that you have to put that `.htaccess` file into the folder `test/1` - is this the case?

Comment: exactly, all the files are in folder "1" and this folder is in the folder "test"

Comment: Have I given enough information now? I'm looking for a solution to this problem and I don't know anymore

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas how. To solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found a solution to my problem.
I will share it, maybe it will be useful to someone.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/1/

#Rewrite for index.php?page=xxxx
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

I added the command: `RewriteBase` - where we write the path to the place on the server where the files are located